# ui-select: expected expression, got . (point)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-select

I installed the latest `angular-ui-select` (v0.12) alongside `angular` v1.2.27. My page won't load. I get:

```
expected expression, got . (a point)
```

That refers to this context in my vendor.js:

```
    !function(){"use strict";var e={TA
    }]);
    /*!
    * ui-select
   * http://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select
   * Version: 0.12.0 - 2015-05-28T07:44:11.364Z
   * License: MIT
   */.ui-select-highlight{
    ^^^ here, at the point.
```

What's going on ? What can I investigate ?

Let's check the requisites for ui-select:

- angular >= 1.2.18: OK
- ngSanitize module: OK (tried to load it after and before, no difference)
- install with bower and include its files, js before css

my `app.js`:

```
angular.module('abelujo', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ui.select',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap',
```

`bower.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angularjs": "1.2.27",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.11.2",
    "angular-cookies": "latest",
    "angular-mocks": "latest",
    "angular-resource": "latest",
    "angular-route": "latest",
    "angular-ui-select": "0.12",
    "angular-sanitize": "latest",
    "angular-ui-router": "latest",
    "bootstrap": "3.3",
    "jquery"   : "~1.9",
    "underscore": "latest",
    "datejs": "latest"
},
```

Here I don't understand: I get `bower_components/angular/angular.js` version 1.3.15 and `bower_components/angularjs/angular.js` version asked, 1.2.27. Looks like the 1.3 is a dependency of ui-select.

in my `gulpfile.js`:

```
var vendorJsFiles = [
  'static/bower_components/angularjs/angular.min.js',
  'static/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js',
  'static/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js',
  'static/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js',
  'static/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js',
  'static/bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.min.js',
  'static/bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.min.css',
  'static/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js',
  'static/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js',
    'static/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js',
  'static/bower_components/underscore/underscore-min.js',
    'static/bower_components/datejs/build/production/date.min.js',
];
```

Thanks for any tips !

Comment: It seems you have CSS inside a Javascript

Comment: Oh yes totally !! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your gulpfile

```
 var vendorJsFiles = [
  /*other files*/
  'static/bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.min.js',
  'static/bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.min.css', //here is the mistake
```

You have css concatenated with javascript.